# Get currentmilliseconds in postgres

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, datetime, date, time

I'm working on timestamp/datetime in my application. I'm using postgres db. 
What is the way to get current milliseconds (something like 1412706599000) in postgres?

Answer (score 5):

```
select extract(epoch from current_timestamp) * 1000;
```

More details in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

Comment: Exactly what i looked for.